# asp.net webform will not let me run javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I've just followed this very basic code on Youtube and it works perfectly.  However, I go to try the same code on my asp.net webforms website, have tried it in both chrome and edge, and javascript doesn't seem to want to run.  Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?  I am using Visual Studio 2015. I must have a setting turned off somewhere or something as it does not make any sense to me why a basic alert is failing to run.

Here is the basic code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="webform.aspx.cs"     Inherits="webform" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">



<title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function pleaseWork(){
        alert("this is running");
        };


</script>


</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">


    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"/>


</form>
</body>
</html>



protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "mykey",  "pleaseWork();", true); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need this to execute on the client, then you probably don't need any server side controls for it. So the head section doesn't need to run on the server.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="pleaseWork();"/>
```

OR

```
<input type="button" value="Button2" onclick ="pleaseWork();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button is missing an `onclick` attribute, so `Button1_Click` is not being called.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: I thought that too, but still does not make a difference. Very confused!